# React Native Android Static Local Image

Tags: react-native

I've a problem with local image. My react native version is **0.14.2**.

I have a file index.android.js in my repository App with this code :

```
<Image source={require('./house.png')} style={styles.image}/>
```

It works if I put my image in App and in App/assets. If I just put my image in App, it doesn't work.

Then, I want write my code like this :

```
<Image source={require('./img/house.png')} style={styles.image}/>
```

But, if I put my image in App/img, it doesn't work. Even if I add my image in App/assets/img, it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to answer but I don't have enough data. Can you post some logs (packager log and adb logcat) when trying to load these images?

Answer (score 0):

Images are loaded relative to your `.js` file. So if you have

```
require('./img/image.png')
```

In `App/index.android.js`, the image should be placed in `App/img/image.png`.

There's no special `assets/` folder.

Comment: It's the problem. When I put my image.png in App/img/image.png, it doesn't work. I have a white place on my page at the place of my image.

Comment: See my comment on the question: please provide some logs. Also, what is in your `styles.image`?

Comment: var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  image: {
  width: 217,
  height: 138,
  },
});

Comment: I haven't interesting log with adb logcat. My packager log when I refresh : [3:04:58 PM] <START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true
[3:04:58 PM] <END>   request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true (31ms)
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2015:14:04:59 +0000] "GET /flow/ HTTP/1.1" 404 18 "-" "okhttp/2.4.0"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. Does this repro if you create a new app (with `react-native init`)?

Comment: Yes, I've the same problem with an other app. I work with another person, it's the same for him. We work on Windows.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think we've tested the new asset system on Windows. Can you file a bug at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues? Thanks!